# Html to print caption before table header in multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is the the html code. I am very new to html.I need to help to print caption before table header. All captions are printing at top in below code. Please help

I need print Caption QACheck:- NIC1 Then Table Header, again caption QACheck:- NIC2 the table header and so on.

I came to know caption is deprecated from Scott Marcus in below comments.

What i need is Before table header I need put Description of the table in this case QACheck:- NIC1, QACheck:- NIC2, QACheck:- NIC3 is the description of the tables.

Please let me know if any more info needed.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>

        <style>
        p {
            font-family : Calibri;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bolder;
            text-align : left;
        }

        p.fade {
            color : #CCCCCC;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        em  {
            font-style : italic ;
            font-size : 16px;
            font-weight: lighter ;
        }
        em.pass {
            font-style : italic ;
            font-size : 16px;
            color: green ;
        }
        em.fail {
            font-style : italic ;
            font-size : 16px;
            color: red ;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        hr {
            align: left ;
            margin-left: 0px ;
            width: 500px;
            height:1px;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        tr {
            padding: 4px;
            text-align: center;
            border-right:2px solid #FFFFFF;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

        th {
            background-color: #cceeff;
            color: black;
            padding: 4px;
            border-right:2px solid #FFFFFF;
        }


        </style>

        <body> 
            <table>
<caption>QACheck:- NIC1</caption>
<tr>
<th>Parameters</th>
<th> Output</th>
<th> QACheck_Status</th>
<th> Reason</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Device</td>
<td> Alias</td>
<td> ok</td>
<td> NOthing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Game</td>
<td> CriKet</td>
<td style='color:red'> Failed</td>
<td> "Not Played well"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>

<caption>QACheck:- NIC2</caption>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Parameters</th>
<th> Output</th>
<th> QACheck_Status</th>
<th> Reason</th>
</tr>
<tr>

<tr>
<td>Device</td>
<td> Alias</td>
<td> ok</td>
<td> NOthing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Game</td>
<td> CriKet</td>
<td style='color:red'> Failed</td>
<td> "Not Played well"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
<caption>QACheck:- NIC3</caption>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Parameters</th>
<th> Output</th>
<th> QACheck_Status</th>
<th> Reason</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Device</td>
<td> Alias</td>
<td> ok</td>
<td> NOthing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Game</td>
<td> CriKet</td>
<td> Pass</td>
<td> "NA"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>

        </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your HTML is invalid overall and needs fixing to properly answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have not closed table tag**
You should open table tag before caption and close it after all the tr tags and then open other table

```css
th{
width:150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>

        <style>
        p {
            font-family : Calibri;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bolder;
            text-align : left;
        }

        p.fade {
            color : #CCCCCC;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        em  {
            font-style : italic ;
            font-size : 16px;
            font-weight: lighter ;
        }
        em.pass {
            font-style : italic ;
            font-size : 16px;
            color: green ;
        }
        em.fail {
            font-style : italic ;
            font-size : 16px;
            color: red ;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        hr {
            align: left ;
            margin-left: 0px ;
            width: 500px;
            height:1px;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        tr {
            padding: 4px;
            text-align: center;
            border-right:2px solid #FFFFFF;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

        th {
            background-color: #cceeff;
            color: black;
            padding: 4px;
            border-right:2px solid #FFFFFF;
        }


        </style>

        <body> 
            <table>
<caption>QACheck:- NIC1</caption>
<tr>
<th>Parameters</th>
<th> Output</th>
<th> QACheck_Status</th>
<th> Reason</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Device</td>
<td> Alias</td>
<td> ok</td>
<td> NOthing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Game</td>
<td> CriKet</td>
<td style='color:red'> Failed</td>
<td> "Not Played well"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
<table>

<caption>QACheck:- NIC2</caption>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Parameters</th>
<th> Output</th>
<th> QACheck_Status</th>
<th> Reason</th>
</tr>
<tr>

<tr>
<td>Device</td>
<td> Alias</td>
<td> ok</td>
<td> NOthing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Game</td>
<td> CriKet</td>
<td style='color:red'> Failed</td>
<td> "Not Played well"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
</table><table>
<caption>QACheck:- NIC3</caption>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Parameters</th>
<th> Output</th>
<th> QACheck_Status</th>
<th> Reason</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Device</td>
<td> Alias</td>
<td> ok</td>
<td> NOthing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Game</td>
<td> CriKet</td>
<td> Pass</td>
<td> "NA"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>

        </body> 
    </html>
```

Update: used css to set size for the same width of all the columns

Comment: Table aliment is changing. I need same width for all the rows

Comment: @kitty i updated my answer please check now. accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You have many HTML errors, but the biggest is that you seem to have 3 tables, but haven't closed the first two of them which is causing the one table to have 3 captions.

You have several empty `tr` elements.

You have omitted the `head` section of the document.

You also have an error in your CSS where you used the `align` property and should have used only `margin:0;` (which you already had):

```
  hr {
        /* you had align:left; */
        margin-left: 0px ;
        width: 500px;
        height:1px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <style>
        p {
            font-family : Calibri;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bolder;
            text-align : left;
        }

        p.fade {
            color : #CCCCCC;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        em  {
            font-style : italic ;
            font-size : 16px;
            font-weight: lighter ;
        }
        em.pass {
            font-style : italic ;
            font-size : 16px;
            color: green ;
        }
        em.fail {
            font-style : italic ;
            font-size : 16px;
            color: red ;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        hr {
            text-align: left;
            margin-left: 0px ;
            width: 500px;
            height:1px;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        tr {
            padding: 4px;
            text-align: center;
            border-right:2px solid #FFFFFF;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

        th {
            background-color: #cceeff;
            color: black;
            padding: 4px;
            border-right:2px solid #FFFFFF;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body> 

  <table>
    <caption>QACheck:- NIC1</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Parameters</th>
      <th> Output</th>
      <th> QACheck_Status</th>
      <th> Reason</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Device</td>
      <td> Alias</td>
      <td> ok</td>
      <td> NOthing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Game</td>
      <td> CriKet</td>
      <td style='color:red'> Failed</td>
      <td> "Not Played well"</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </table>
  

  <table>
    <caption>QACheck:- NIC2</caption>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Parameters</th>
      <th> Output</th> 
      <th> QACheck_Status</th>
      <th> Reason</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Device</td>
      <td> Alias</td>
      <td> ok</td>
      <td> NOthing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Game</td>
      <td> CriKet</td>
      <td style='color:red'> Failed</td>
      <td> "Not Played well"</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </table> 




  <table>
    <caption>QACheck:- NIC3</caption>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Parameters</th>
      <th> Output</th>
      <th> QACheck_Status</th>
      <th> Reason</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Device</td>
      <td> Alias</td>
      <td> ok</td>
      <td> NOthing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Game</td>
      <td> CriKet</td>
      <td> Pass</td>
      <td> "NA"</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </table>



</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: `<caption>` has NOT been deprecated: https://developers.whatwg.org/tabular-data.html#the-caption-element Your link says nothing about it being deprecated.